# Filling torch tensor with zeros after certain index

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch

Given a 3d tenzor, say:
`batch x sentence length x embedding dim`

```
a = torch.rand((10, 1000, 96))
```

and an array(or tensor) of actual lengths for each sentence

```
lengths =  torch .randint(1000,(10,))
```

`outputs tensor([ 370., 502., 652., 859., 545., 964., 566., 576.,1000., 803.])`

How to fill tensor ‘a’ with zeros after certain index along dimension 1 (sentence length) according to tensor ‘lengths’ ?

I want smth like that :

```
a[ : , lengths : , : ]  = 0
```

One way of doing it (slow if batch size is big enough):

```
for i_batch in range(10):
    a[ i_batch  , lengths[i_batch ] : , : ]  = 0
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it using a binary mask.
Using `lengths` as column-indices to `mask` we indicate where each sequence ends (note that we make `mask` longer than `a.size(1)` to allow for sequences with full length).
Using [`cumsum()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.1.0/torch.html#torch.cumsum) we set all entries in `mask` after the seq len to 1.

```py
mask = torch.zeros(a.shape[0], a.shape[1] + 1, dtype=a.dtype, device=a.device)
mask[(torch.arange(a.shape[0]), lengths)] = 1
mask = mask.cumsum(dim=1)[:, :-1]  # remove the superfluous column
a = a * (1. - mask[..., None])     # use mask to zero after each column
```

For `a.shape = (10, 5, 96)`, and `lengths = [1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 0, 4, 4, 1, 3]`.
Assigning 1 to respective `lengths` at each row, `mask` looks like:

```py
mask = 
tensor([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]])
```

After `cumsum` you get

```py
mask = 
tensor([[0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
        [0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 1.]])
```

Note that it exactly has zeros where the valid sequence entries are and ones beyond the lengths of the sequences. Taking `1 - mask` gives you exactly what you want.

Enjoy ;)