# Pytorch cut 2d array by lengths on first dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, pytorch

I have a 2d array, let's say of size `torch.tensor(batch_size, 1000)`.  The 1000 array from the second dimension is actually variable length.  I have a second array of size `[batch_size]` containing the length for each rows...

Here is an example code snippet:

```
# preds is the 2d array of size [batch_size, 1000]
# lengths is a 1d array containing the lengths of each row of preds
res_pred = []
for i in range(len(preds)):
    length = lengths[i].item()
    res_pred += [preds[i][:length]]

result = torch.cat(res_pred).flatten()
```

I do the same thing for my targets and then I can apply a loss function to both.

I was wondering if there was a single vectorized operation I could do to extract all `batch_size` vectors of variable lengths and `torch.cat` them together. Right now I am looping on the first dimension, but this feel slow.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you add an example of your array? Also adding your slow code with loop would help to understand the expected output.

Comment: how do you expect to `torch.cat` vectors of different lengths? are you going to create a *single* vector of size `(1, sum(vector_lengths))`?

Comment: @AndreasK., I added a code example.  I should have done that first.  Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure there's an efficient way of doing what you want. Have you considered, as an alternative, to create a mask with the same shape as `res_pred` and compute the loss only for values that has 1 in the mask? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57548180/1714410) might help you create the mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a 2D mask tensor with the number of True's in i-th row given by `lengths[i]`. Here's one example:

```
batch_size = 6
n = 5

preds = torch.arange(batch_size * n).reshape(batch_size, n)
# tensor([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
#         [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
#         [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
#         [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
#         [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
#         [25, 26, 27, 28, 29]])

#lengths = np.random.randint(0, n+1, batch_size)
lengths = torch.randint(0, n+1, (batch_size, ))
# tensor([2, 0, 5, 3, 3, 2])
```

Let's create the mask and get our result (probably there is a better way to create such a mask, but that's what I came up with):

```
#mask = np.tile(range(n), (batch_size,1)) < lengths[:,None]
mask = torch.arange(n).repeat((batch_size,1)) < lengths[:, None]
# tensor([[ True,  True, False, False, False],
#        [False, False, False, False, False],
#        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
#        [ True,  True,  True, False, False],
#        [ True,  True,  True, False, False],
#        [ True,  True, False, False, False]])

#result = preds[mask]
result = torch.masked_select(preds, mask)
# tensor([0, 1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20, 21, 22, 25, 26])
```

This produces the same result as your code:

```
res_pred = []
for i in range(len(preds)):
    length = lengths[i].item()
    res_pred += [preds[i][:length]]

result = torch.cat(res_pred).flatten()
```

Comment: I edited the answer so that it uses pytorch instead of numpy (the numpy's solution is commented).