# Chose rows of 3d Tensor based on some repeated indices. Tricky Slicing

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch, tensor

So this is a tricky bit of Tensor slicing I'm trying.

I have a tensor `A` which is 3d

```
>> A.shape
torch.Size([60, 10, 16])
```

So this tensor is composed of 5 different data samples, where in `dim=0` we have cuts at `split_ids = [10, 14, 10, 12, 14]` i.e first `10` elements belong to `sample1`; next `14` belong to `sample2` & so on.. I can split the tensor in such a way:

```
>> torch.split(A, split_ids, dim=0)
(tensor([[[-0.3888, -...Backward>), tensor([[[ 2.6473e-0...Backward>), tensor([[[ 1.1621,  ...Backward>), tensor([[[ 0.1953, -...Backward>), tensor([[[ 8.1993e-0...Backward>))
```

This comprises of tuple of 5 elements (or 5 tensors), of shapes `Size(10,10,16)`;`Size(14,10,16)`; and so on for the splits we had.

Now, comes the tricky part - I have another indices mapping that I have derived some previous processing for each of these individual splits. Its a list of 1d tensors like this:

```
>> reverse_map
[tensor([1, 2, 2, 1, ...='cuda:0'), tensor([ 7,  7,  9, ...='cuda:0'), tensor([7, 7, 4, 3, ...='cuda:0'), tensor([ 9,  4,  9, ...='cuda:0'), tensor([ 0,  0,  0, ...='cuda:0')]
>> reverse_map[0]
tensor([1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 6, 1, 7, 1, 2, 7, 4, 5, 3, 4, 9, 7,
        7, 3, 8, 7, 7, 7], device='cuda:0')
```

So I need to basically use these indices and pull the count of these indices from the above split tensors i.e For `tensor.Size(10,10,16)` I need to pull [0, 0:3, :] which is for index `0` in dim=0, I need to pull 0:3 in dim=1 because there are 3 `0`'s in the indexing. Then at index `1` I need to pull first 4 vectors since there are 4 `1`'s.. and so on.

Whats the best way to do this ? Does `scatter_()` help here ?

Comment: There are 7 `1`s in `reverse_map`. Why do you need to pull only 4 - this part is unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a combination of [`torch.bincount`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.bincount.html#torch.bincount) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57550753/1714410) can give you what you want.

For simplicity, let's focus on the first tensor split from `A` and the first `reverse_map`. You can then apply this code to the other splits and `reverse_map`s. Let `source` be the first split of shape `(10, 10, 16)`.

Here's how it goes:

```py
# inputs
source = torch.arange(10*10*16).view(10, 10, 16)
reverse_map = torch.tensor(tensor([1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 6, 1, 7, 1, 2, 7, 4, 5, 3, 4, 9, 7, 7, 3, 8, 7, 7, 7])

# how many columns to pull for each row - use bincount to find out!
lengths = torch.bincount(reverse_map, minlength=source.shape[0])

# use a mask to pull the elements
mask = torch.zeros(source.shape[0], source.shape[1] + 1, dtype=source.dtype, device=source.device)
mask[(torch.arange(source.shape[0]), lengths)] = 1
mask = mask.cumsum(dim=1)[:, :-1] == 0

# expand the mask to dim=2 as well and pull the elements
out = source[mask[..., None].expand(-1, -1, source.shape[2])]

# since you pull different number of columns per row, you loose the shape of source. You need a final split to recover it
target = torch.split(out, (lengths * source.shape[2]).cpu().numpy().tolist())

target = [t_.view(-1, source.shape[2]) for t_ in target]
```

The output `target` is a list of 2-D tensors with varying number of rows (according to the counts of `reverse_map` and `source.shape[2]` columns in each.

Comment: Yes `torch.bincount` is a good usage here. First bincount and then build a `mask = A < bincount` and use that mask to pull selected tensors out.