# unable to pad the array using np.pad and reshape

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have these tensors

```
x = array.Size([110,3])
    array.Size([126, 3])
    array.Size([64, 3])
    array.Size([132, 3])
    array.Size([130, 3])
    array.Size([20, 3])
```

pad to this (maxshape, 3) and reshape to (maxshape, 2, 3)?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve.
You can reshape all tensors to `(?, 2, 3)` and then stack them along the first dimension:

```py
y = torch.cat([x_.reshape(-1, 2, 3) for x_ in x], dim=0)
```

With `y.shape = torch.Size([559, 2, 3])`.

Note that in [`reshape`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.13/generated/torch.reshape.html) you can specify one of the dimensions as `-1`. This will make pytorch infer the shape of that dimension given the input shape and the other arguments provided.

Comment: this gave an error RuntimeError: shape '[-1, 2, 3]' is invalid for input of size 64 
how else to do it if I want to pad them with zeros to a maximum shape along the first dimension? can you please provide a padding example for this? would their shape also be (-,2,3)?

Comment: @user4556432 You cannot `reshape` a tensor of shape `64` to some shape `(...,3)` - the number of elements simply does not divide by 3. You need to be consistent.

Comment: @user4556432 [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57550753/1714410) might be helpful

Comment: if padding it then reshaping is possible, right?

Comment: @user4556432 correctly using padding should give you more control over the `shape`

Comment: that's not I want, can you please help with F.pad if I want to pad size(0) I'm not following the concepts with top, left when I want to pad the first dimension?